# How can I convert XML to XMLList?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-cc

I have an XML object and want to convert it to XMLList. Because I'm getting this error:

```
 TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert XMLList@7ff5fee1c2f1 to XML.
```

Here's my code:

```
GenerateMenu(event.target.parent, xPos, yPos, event.target.xmlNode);
```

Here's how the property defined:

```
mc.xmlNode = xml.child(i);
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: you don't convert one to the other, it's either a xml or a xmllist but it can't be both. You'll fix your error by passing the correct type not by converting which is not possible in that case.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I used XMLList instead of XML and it worked fine.

Comment: The error says the opposite, it says you have an `XMLList` but it expects an `XML` object. In those cases you can just use the `[0]` element of the `XMLList`, which is an `XML` object.